# Konva.js images appearing on desktop but not mobile

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs

I am trying to draw a saved Konva.js stage that includes images. It is working as expected on desktop (Chrome and Safari) but is not working in mobile Chrome or mobile Safari (iOS; I haven't been able to test Android).

I've used `console.log` to confirm that `image.draw()` is firing on mobile with the correct asset, but the canvas remains blank.

Is there possibly some race condition I'm overlooking that is more prevalent on mobile devices? I'm new to Konva and to canvas, so thorough responses are greatly appreciated.

Relevant JS code is included below:

```
var imageData = {
  billy: {
    x: 146,
    y: 126,
    src: '/assets/billy.png'
  },
  nox: {
    x: 279,
    y: 126,
    src: '/assets/nox.png'
  },
  battleMap: {
    x: 2100,
    y: 2100,
    src: '/assets/map.jpg'
  }
};

socket.on('stage', data => {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    stage = Konva.Node.create(json, 'container');
    mapLayer = stage.findOne("#mapLayer");
    tokenLayer = stage.findOne("#tokenLayer");

    var images = stage.find("Image");

    images.map(image => {
      var id = image.attrs.id;
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        stage.findOne('#' + id).image(imageObj);
        console.log("drawing " + imageObj.src);
        image.draw();

      };
      imageObj.src = imageData[id].src;
    });
});
```

Comment: After further digging, it appears this is related to the size of the Konva stage. It was set to 2100 x 2100 px and reducing one or both sizes allowed it to render on mobile. I still don't totally understand why it's an issue -- it seems like mobile browser limits are notably higher than that, but at least it's "fixed" for now.

Comment: why do you need so big stage on the mobile?

If you create a stage with the size of `2100x2100`, the real canvas size may be bigger (on HDPI devices, like retina).